# Calling object in array in Node js ejs file

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

Good work everyone!

I have a project that I wrote with Node js.
In this project, I have a schema structure as follows.

```
const debt = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  medicine: [{

    data: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Medicine',
    },
    quantity: {
      type: Number,
      default: 1
    }
  }],
  total: {
    type: Schema.Types.Decimal128,
    default: 0,
  },
  status: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});
```

```
const medicine = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
  },
  price: {
    type: Schema.Types.Decimal128,
    required: true,
  },
  medicineType: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
  },
  image: {
    type: String,
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});
```

I am able to successfully add data to this schema from postman.
But I can't read the data in the ejs file, how can I do that?

I can read the data through the console and the code I use on the console is as follows:

```
const debt = await Debt.find({}).populate('medicine.data').sort('-createdAt');

console.log(JSON.stringify(debt[0].medicine[0].data));
```

The above code successfully returns both the schema it references and its own data.

```
<% for(let i=0; i< debt.medicine.length; i++) { %>

<input type="checkbox" id="<%= medicine[i]._id%>" name="medicine"  checked value="<%= debt.medicine[i].data%>">
<label for="<%= medicine[i]._id%>"><%= JSON.stringify(debt.medicine[i].data) %> - Select %> </label>

<% } %>
```

But when I do this in the ejs file, it only returns the id and quantity values. When I print it in the console, I can access all the data as in the medicine schema.
Why can't I access the ejs file? can you help me?

The data it returns when I print it in the console

```
{"_id":"624e0b3633533f3a31e3dc6a","name":"Arveles","price":{"$numberDecimal":"19"},"medicineType":"Pill","description":"Medicine","image":"/uploads/1649281846287-medicine1.jpeg","createdAt":"2022-04-06T21:50:46.294Z","__v":0}
```

When I print it on ejs it returns a value like this

```
{"data":"624e0b3633533f3a31e3dc6a","quantity":2,"_id":"62537484a05359a8cf356fef"}
```

Comment: So your code is something like:
```app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
   const debt = someGetDebtFunction();
   console.log(debt);
   res.render('YourTemplateName', debt);
}```
and your render is doing the other console log? It would be odd if the template render is losing properties, but I feel some in between code must be doing something different with debt for this to happen. If you paste the full object to a variable and pass into the template, does it do the same thing?

Comment: Unfortunately, what you suggested didn't work.

Comment: You need to show us everything in your route handler from loading the data up to and including rendering the template. My guess is there's a typo type error somewhere.

Comment: I shared the solution of the problem, thanks dude, it's a mistake as you said.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I just solved the situation, I did not correctly populate the page through the control structure...
Maybe it may happen to others, in such structures, it is necessary to send two data inside the populate process.

Solution to the problem:

```
const debt = await Debt.findOne({ _id: req.params.id }).populate('medicine.data');
```

```
populate('medicine.data')
```

I can say that the whole process revolves here.